# Solving mysql complex query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an mysql table which has structure like below:

```
ProjectID | QuestionID | LocationID | Points | Wave |
    12    |     121    |    1201    |   5    |   1  |
    12    |     122    |    1201    |   5    |   1  |
    12    |     121    |    1202    |   5    |   1  |
    12    |     122    |    1202    |   5    |   1  |
    12    |     121    |    1201    |   4    |   2  |
    12    |     122    |    1201    |   4    |   2  |
```

now i want to write a query that sums the points of each location with each question no matter the what the wave is. for example the result of the query should display like this.

```
ProjectID | QuestionID | LocationID | Points |
    12    |     121    |    1201    |   9    |
    12    |     122    |    1201    |   9    |
    12    |     121    |    1202    |   5    |
    12    |     122    |    1202    |   5    |
```

Any possible solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: i make a for loop in php script and got the Locations and then against those Locations i get the points. but this takes a long time to execute. So thats why i want to this in one query. and i don't know which thing to use.

Comment: Where's the complexity here?

Comment: @DDay Explain through query is better than words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the solution you need:

```
Select ProjectID ,QuestionID ,LocationID , sum(point) from `table` group by ProjectID ,QuestionID ,LocationID
```